# Number of charges and electric potential

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, potential, capacitance

Suppose we have an isolated conducting sphere that has a neutral charge, then we extract electrons from the sphere (for example with an electron gun) in such a way that it is positively charged, how can I calculate how many electrons I must extract from the sphere to charge it to a certain potential $V$?

Comment: Sketch: a conducting sphere of radius $R$ behaves like a point charge with the same total charge at and beyond its surface. If you can figure out the charge needed for a point charge to create the potential $V$ at a distance $R$ from the point charge, then you know the sphere must have that same amount of total charge to have that potential at its surface. Then divide that amount of charge by the charge of an electron, up to a sign!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to compute the total charge difference by use of one of the following methods:

1. *The definition of electric potential for a conducting sphere with radius $R$, i.e. $V = \frac{q}{{4\pi {\varepsilon _0}R}}$*: This yields $\Delta q = 4\pi {\varepsilon _0}R\Delta V$.

or

2. *The definition of capacitance of a sphere, i.e., $C={4\pi {\varepsilon _0}R}$ and then using $C=q/V$*: From $\Delta q = C \Delta V$, again, we obtain $\Delta q = 4\pi {\varepsilon _0}R\Delta V$.

Finally, the total amount of electron that you have to extract is found by the relation of quantization of charge as

$$n = \frac{{\Delta q}}{{\left| e \right|}},$$

where $\left| e \right|$ is [the elementary charge (of electron)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge).

Answer (score -1):

What you need is the [capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Capacitance_of_conductors_with_simple_shapes) of the sphere.